# How to make abstraction for Base class using virtual functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have the following structure

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(Type);
    virtual render
}

class A
{
public:
    Base(Type == A);
    void render()
}

class B
{
public:
    Base(Type == B);
    void render()
}

void client_function()
{
    Base baseObject(A);
    //Base is an instance of class A
    baseObject.render()//runs class A render
}
```

There are things in the above code that are not c++ as far as I am aware, they are closely related to pattern matching found in Haskell for example, but this is the best way I could find to illustrate my question without already knowing the answer ;)

In writing I want the client to be able to create a base object and pass the type of object as an argument, the correct specification of the object is returned and the client need not care less about it, just knows that running render will run the correct specific render.

Please feel free to ask questions if I have been unclear :)

Comment: You might want to start with a basic C++ book or tutorial, it seems as if you are missing some basic concepts of inheritance and all the other Object Oriented concepts. If what you want does not fall into that category, you might be looking at the CRTP (static polymorphism), but deciding one for the other without greater knowledge of the exact problem is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to read about virtual functions and inheritance:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/proper-inheritance.html

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html

Answer (score 2):

You need **run-time polymorphism**. There is not much important part of constructor. You have to inherit the `Base` into `A` and `B`. For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void render ();  // <--- declare 'virtual'
  virtual ~Base();  // <--- very much needed to avoid undefined behavior
};
class A : public Base //<---- inheritance
{
public:
  void render();  // <--- this also becomes 'virtual'
};
...
```

Now you can use as per your requirement.

```
Base *baseObject = new A();  // <----- need to use pointer (or reference)
(*baseObject).render();  // <--- other way to write: baseObject->render();
delete baseObject;
```

Comment: `(*baseObject).render();` could also be written `baseObject->render();` (if my memory does not betray me)

Comment: typo in class A ? (void void)

Comment: @duedlOr, really a good catch. Though I was intending to give minimal example, this is the key point (which OP must never miss).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question. In C++ you cannot choose your base class at runtime, but you certainly can have your base class depend from the derived class. This is done by using templates and what is known as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename T> class Base {
public:
    virtual void render(T *) {}
};

class A : public Base<A>
{
public:
    void render(A * t) {}
};

class B : public Base<B>
{
public:
    void render(B * t) {}
};

void client_function() {
    A a1;
    A a2;
    a1.render(&a2); // calls A::render
    a1.Base<A>::render(&a2); // calls Base<A>::render
    Base<A> * ba = &a1;
    ba->render(&a2); // calls A::render
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is exactly what inheritance is for: creating object from a class hierarchy that specializes a functionality.

In your example, apart from syntax problems, things will work as you expect, i.e. method `A::render` will be called, even if you don't know at compile time that object, declared as a `Base`, is indeed a `A`. That's virtual inheritance magicness.